Omission of 1-length cycles in permutations notation.
I am revisiting some basics on permutations and this might sound trivial but I don't understand what exactly is omitting 1-length cycles in permutations ?
Most lecture notes or materials say it's a convention, because a permutation of length 1 doesn't do anything.
For example $(123)(4) = (123)$.
We know that $(1)(2)(3) = id$ in $S_3$
if we omit $(3)$ we get $(1)(2)(3) = (1)(2)$
But then $(1)(2)(3)=(1)(2)=(1)$
But this is false because the permutation that fixes $1$ is not same as the one that fixes all elements.

By $(1)$ we don't mean any old permutation that fixes $1$, we mean the permutation consisting entirely of the 1-cycle $(1)$; that is, the permutation doing nothing. We have $(x) = \mathrm{id}$ for all $x$.

It's not required to omit length one cycles, but it is permitted; the convention is that any number that doesn't show up is fixed.
